# I can't find the trash icon anymore

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, trash, gnome-tweak-tool, desktop-icons

I use Ubuntu 19.04 and I can't find the trash icon anymore, not on the taskbar or the desktop.

If I enable it in Tweaks the other icons disappear.

Comment: I just came across this one, I have not used it myself.   https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/48/trash/

Answer (score 2):

Gnome 3.30, which is what Ubuntu 19.04 is using, has disabled the desktop icons. To add them back you have to install the [Desktop Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/) extension from the Gnome Shell Extensions website.

Using Tweaks you can open the Desktop Icons extension preferences and select the option to show the trash icon on the desktop.

**Update**

I found that other users have left comments that state this problem on the extension's website. This means that it is a Desktop Icons extension bug that affects multiple people.

However, I did not find a bug report on the  [extension's gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons) about this issue. Perhaps you could add one to let the developers know about it, if they don't already.

Comment: thanks but i allready did that and still no trash icon in my starter or the desktop.

Comment: Can you add any other icons on your desktop?

Comment: yes i can add my personal map on the desktop the weird thing is when i slide my trashcan on in tweak extention the personal map is removed (even when the slider is on)

Comment: Did you try pressing Alt+F2 and type "r" (without the quotes) and hit Enter to restart the shell after changing the slider? Did you try to uninstall the extension and then install it again?

Comment: yes tryed both none of them work

Comment: @Dendirk please check my updated answer.